# Strategy for day folders in google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

What is the best strategy for creating daily archives of around 10k files per day in gcp?  All files on a day will subsequently be processed.  My dilemma is that gcp cloud storage is flat, so I would have to pick through all the creation dates.  My other idea is to have day buckets, then I can go directly to that bucket.  Which do you think is the better strategy?

Comment: With cloud storage you can only filter by the prefix of your file (the full path included). If you want to select a date, or a range of date, think smartly at your file name creation, for instance `<year>-<month>-<day>-<filename>` or `/<year>/<month>/<day>/<filename>`

Comment: I've done but then I have to get eah blob for its name or creation date as follows:

```
for o in client.list_blobs('twitter_log'):
    print(o.name, o.time_created)

```

I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Yes, it's not a file system, it's a blob storage. With its strengths and weaknesses.

Comment: Did @guillaumeblaquiere manage to answer your question, @user2302244?

Comment: Yes.  I realize, I will just have to process all objects until  find the dates I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GCS List APIs ([JSON](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list), [XML](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/get-bucket-list)), [gsutil ls](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls) and client libraries all allow some kind of `prefix` listing. For example, you can list all objects that start `gs://bucket/archive/YYYY/MM/DD` to get `gs://bucket/archives/YYYY/MM/DD/file01.tgz`, `gs://bucket/archives/YYYY/MM/DD/file02.tgz` etc.

If you are able to structure your archives like this, then when you process files you can use the appropriate prefix to only process one day's files.